# How to turn off checking for constraints and delete all data from a table using Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have a table that needs to be synced with a raw file. This table has foreign keys so I need to disable checking for that and delete all the existing data.

This is what I have.

```
int i = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("ALTER TABLE " + table + "  NOCHECK Constraint All");          
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM " + table);
```

Error

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The DELETE statement conflicted with the
>   REFERENCE constraint "FK_CUST". The conflict
>   occurred in database "table", table "dbo.table".

The statement has been terminated.

The statement has been terminated.
Why didn't the above work? How do I do it?

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that part. For some reason, the alter table command doesn't seem to work

Comment: Try that in SQL Server Manager directly and check if it works there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You are disabling the constraints of the table you want to delete but other tables could depend on that table. Even if you disable all the necessary constraints to delete that table, after you delete it you won't be able to re-enable the constraints. You will need to delete related table rows too.

2) If you need to delete a table completely always use TRUNCATE.

How to disable and enable contraints for all the tables:

```
-- Disable all constraints for database
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"

-- Enable all constraints for database
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all"
```

Source: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/12/02/sql-server-how-to-disable-and-enable-all-constraint-for-table-and-database/

Comment: The previous developer had turned off check constraints for all the tables in one go. That's the mistake I made. Thank you.